# Sign In with Apple Not forwarding email

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-sign-in

I implemented SignIn with apple into my app. It works fine.
After signIn, server will send OTP code to verify that email.

But there is one issue. If user select **"Hide My Email"** then I am not getting OTP verification email.

Is there something do it from our side?
I re-search that & found that it may need **iCloud+ subscription** for "Hide my email" feature, is it true?

I am not sure about that.

Thank you,

Comment: The paid "Hide my email" is for a custom email, like an alias vs the private relay address that some companies are blocking.

Comment: ok, I got something like privately.appleid.com but no email forwarding

Comment: If you use *Sign In with Apple*, the email address has been verified by Apple. Why do you need a verification email at all?